# MYSQL- Multiple column value change

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to change the values of 150 columns to the following;

```
 '0 = Not provided'
' 1 = Yes '
' 2 = No '
```

I was able to do this using a case statement for each column.  But the problem is it creates puts everything into one column. Is there a way to do it for each individual column without writing 150 case statements?  The columns need to be in a specific order.

example:

```
SELECT  CASE 
          WHEN Answer.Question1_ID is null THEN 'Not Provided'
          WHEN Answer.Question1_ID = 1 THEN 'Yes'
          WHEN Answer.Question1_ID = 2 Then 'No'
End as 'Question1',
  CASE 
          WHEN Answer.Question2_ID is null THEN 'Not Provided'
          WHEN Answer.Question2_ID = 1 THEN 'Yes'
          WHEN Answer.Question2_ID = 2 Then 'No'
End as 'Question2'
```

.
.
.

From Answer

Comment: This is why you *never* create tables like this: querying them later becomes a nightmare.

Comment: WOW... 150 columns :D

Comment: so you have Question1 -> Question150? You really really REALLY should have normalized that table,and then it'be a simple/trivial update query on the child table.

Comment: I think you can do this with dynamic SQL, but yeah 150 columns is pretty massive.

Comment: The problem is that you have your questions in separate columns.  If you had the questions in separate rows, then you would not have to repeat the exercise 150 times.

Comment: Maybe you can transpose the table and then do it

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do it for each individual column without writing 150 case statements?

No.

You can use a program to write the case statements if need be.